# Plotly replace x label with image

Tags: python, plotly

I have a graph in plotly which I want to replace the x labels.[image]

I pasted this graph as an example. At the bottom you will see ARI, ATL, BAL, etc. I was wondering if its possible to replace these with images? Icons?

Comment: Images can be added as annotations to scatter plots, but I don't know of any examples of images on the x-axis. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432916/plotly-replace-x-axis-tick-labels-with-images/65434612#65434612) I gave in response to a similar question. Are you the same person? You have been presented with the same graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- same approach that @r-begginers provided in referenced answer
- have sourced all logos from **kaggle**.  Used **PIL** for encoding
- have synthesized as an axis by creating a second trace with a -ve percentage and used that plot area to place logos
- have set **xaxis** to invisible so hover provided the team abbreviation

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import plotly.express as px
from PIL import Image

# fmt: off
# download data set
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/anzhemeng/nfl-team-logos"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
# fmt: on
zfile.extractall("nfl-logos")
df = pd.DataFrame(Path.cwd().joinpath("nfl-logos").glob("*.png"), columns=["filename"])
df["team"] = df["filename"].apply(lambda d: d.stem)
df["passResult"] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df))
df = df.sort_values("team")

fig = px.scatter(df, x="team", y="passResult").add_traces(
    px.scatter(df, "team", np.full(len(df), -0.05))
    .update_traces(marker_color="rgba(0,0,0,0)", hovertemplate="%{x}")
    .data
)

for x in fig.data[0].x:
    fig.add_layout_image(
        source=Image.open(df.loc[df["team"].eq(x), "filename"].values[0]),
        x=x,
        y=-0.01,
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        xanchor="center",
        sizex=1,
        sizey=1,
    )

fig.update_layout(xaxis={"visible":False})
```

[image]

Comment: I see, there is such an approach. Up vote!

Comment: @Rob Raymond, is there a way to place the ticks under the plot and not inside? When I try this with larger images the Y-axis spans into the negatives.

Comment: another option would be use a second y-axis for ticks and set domains of both y-axes