# How can I change the symbol of a plotly scatterplot to a svg file

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, scatter-plot, plotly-python

I'm trying to make a graph where the dots of a scatterplot are chess pieces. For now the code is very simple:

```
fig = px.scatter(
    x = df_game.x, 
    y = df_game.y,
    color = df_game.color,
    symbol = df_game.icon,
    opacity = 0.1
    )
fig.show()
```

It returns this graph:
[image]

But I want something like this one:

[image]

My dataframe contains the (x, y) position for every piece on every turn, like this:

```
   turn piece color  x  y          icon
0     0     r     w  1  1  icons/wr.svg
1     0     n     w  1  2  icons/wn.svg
2     0     b     w  1  3  icons/wb.svg
3     0     q     w  1  4  icons/wq.svg
4     0     k     w  1  5  icons/wk.svg
```

and the icons that I want to use are in the column `icon`.

How can I change the default icons to my .svgs?

Comment: If the file format is png, it is easy to handle. See my past [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432916/plotly-replace-x-axis-tick-labels-with-images/65434612#65434612).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to convert an SVG image to a PNG image and display it. The library to be installed is 'cariosvg'. Use it to convert the converted binary to a string in base64 and set it as the reference for the image.

```
import plotly.express as px
import base64
import cairosvg
import io

x = df['x'].tolist()
y = df['y'].tolist()

chess_images = df['icon'].tolist()

fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y)

for i,(src,yy) in enumerate(zip(chess_images, y),start=1):
    img = io.BytesIO(cairosvg.svg2png(url='./data/chess/'+src))
    base_img = base64.b64encode(img.read())
    fig.add_layout_image(
        source='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(base_img.decode()),
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        x=i,
        y=yy-0.25,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="bottom",
        sizex=0.5,
        sizey=0.5,
        layer='above'
    )
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Size xy is a parameter that controls the size of the image to be introduced, so if the image is small, increase the value. If my answer helps you, please accept the answer.