# Plotly scatterplot marker image with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, image, plotly, google-maps-markers

Im struggling with getting plotly in python to show an image for scatterplot data points from a pandas data frame. The current code below will successfully plot the icon in the plot:

```
from PIL import Image
import plotly.express as px
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

##query, get data for a data frame##
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''
                                 SELECT NOTE_DATE as D_DATE, 1 AS Note
                                 FROM MY_NOTES
                                 WHERE (((UID)=(?)))''', connection, params=(UID,))

#Note -- sample data includes a list of dates, and a '1' for each date that a note exists. example:
# D_DATE       Note
# 01/01/2022     1
# 01/02/2022    NaN
# 01/03/2022    NaN
# 01/04/2022     1
# 01/05/2022     1
# 01/06/2022    NaN
# 01/07/2022    NaN

df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query, columns = ['D_DATE', 'Note'])

myIcon = Image.open(myPath+"\images\abc.png")

fig = go.Figure()

# Add trace
fig.add_trace(
   go.Scatter(x=[0, 0.5, 1, 2, 2.2], y=[1.23, 2.5, 0.42, 3, 1])
)
   fig.add_layout_image(
      dict(
           source=myIcon,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            x=2,
            y=1,
            sizex=0.25,
            sizey=0.25,
            xanchor="center",
            yanchor="middle",
            #sizing="contain",
            #opacity=0.8,
            layer="below"
            )
        )

fig.update_traces(textposition="bottom right")

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
   orientation="h",
   yanchor="bottom",
   y=-0.20,
   xanchor="center",
   x=.5
   ),
   margin=dict(
      l=2, #left margin
      r=5, #right margin
      b=20, #bottom margin
      t=25 #top margin
      ))
```

In addition to the note within the code demonstrating sample output, here is an output of `df.head(10).to_dict()`. **But please be aware -- There are no notes in the sample data within the first 10 records.** So all 'Note' entries show nan. When a note exists, there will be a 1 (per the query):

```
{
'D_DATE': {0: Timestamp('2019-10-07 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2019-10-08 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2019-10-09 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2019-10-10 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2019-10-11 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2019-10-12 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2019-10-13 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2019-10-14 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2019-10-15 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2019-10-16 00:00:00')},  
'Note': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan}
}
```

However, when I replace the dummy values with the data frame of dates, and value -- the icon does not appear for the markers. Here is the altered portion of the code:

```
# Add trace
fig.add_trace(
   go.Scatter(x=df["D_DATE"], y=df["Note"])
)
   fig.add_layout_image(
      dict(
           source=myIcon,
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            x=df["D_DATE"],
            y=df["Note"],
            sizex=0.25,
            sizey=0.25,
            xanchor="center",
            yanchor="middle",
            #sizing="contain",
            #opacity=0.8,
            layer="below"
            )
        )
```

What am I missing, why this will not work? The intent is to display the icon  for each Y value from the DF.

**Update:**
I have mild progress, but still not sure why I'm experiencing the behavior that I am.

1. if I set `go.Figure()` **after** `px.scatter`, I get multiple images layered on top of each other (mild progress), but my X axis is no longer a DATE, instead numbers (0, 1, 2, 3...):

```
        myIcon = Image.open(myPath.rstrip('script.py')+"\images\home.png")

        fig = px.scatter(x=df3['D_DATE'], y=df3['Note'])
        fig = go.Figure()

        for(_, col1, col2) in df3.itertuples(name=None):
           fig.add_layout_image(
              dict(
                source=myIcon,
                xref="x",
                yref="y",
                x=col1,
                y=col2,
                sizex=3,
                sizey=3,
                xanchor="center",
                yanchor="middle",
                layer="above"
              )
           )
```

2. If I move `go.Figure()` **before** `px.scatter`, then i have the expected Date x-axis, however, no images are plotted (or shown) in the chart. This chart has markers for y-axis for dates with a note (expecting the image instead).

```
        fig = go.Figure()
        fig = px.scatter(x=df3['D_DATE'], y=df3['Note'])

        for(_, col1, col2) in df3.itertuples(name=None):
           fig.add_layout_image(
              dict(
                source=myIcon,
                xref="x",
                yref="y",
                x=col1,
                y=col2,
                sizex=3,
                sizey=3,
                xanchor="center",
                yanchor="middle",
                layer="above"
              )
           )
```

Comment: Could you please add sample data to instead of `sql_query`, you can write `df.head(10).to_dict()` and copy and paste the result here?

Comment: Updated to include sample data.

Comment: Please , copy paste df.head(10).to_dict() to your question instead of added the data as comments.

Comment: You'll now see the first 10 records from the df. As  noted - first "Note" does not exist within this frame range.

Comment: Please, change the first 10 samples to involve notes.

Comment: No thanks. A "1" will appear for each note. there's nothing more to see in the data. I have confirmed notes exist, this isn't the issue.  I have provided ample data and sample code for someone familiar with the issue to identify where I'm going wrong. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I understand that plotly image display is not configurable in a list or array, but on an image-by-image basis. So if I want to display multiple images, I would use a loop process to determine and add the flag in this case NOTE. If you want to add all of them to a data point, you can do so using the x-axis and y-axis values.

Comment: Yikes. That's unfortunate. I imagine that given the size of my dataframe, that looping would be quite inefficient. Can you provide an example of a potential optimal loop for this scenario?

Comment: Please refer to my previous [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432916/plotly-replace-x-axis-tick-labels-with-images) for similar examples. I am converting and using different images that are locally available. This is easy if it is a single image.

Comment: @r-beginners - I have provided an update with mild progress, but still have the issue outstanding.